# dart angular2 - input in component instantiated in OnInit method

Tags: angular, dart, components

I try to have a component with an input instantiated in the `OnInit` method :

```
 <my-component [myInput]="myInput"></my-component>
```

In my-component, `myInput` is always null, as it is not instantiated in the constructor but in `OnInit` method. I cannot instantiate it in the constructor because I need to call an async method, which is not permitted  in the constructor.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where an when is `myInput` in the parent element set? Have you tried `ngOnChanges()`?. You actually can call async methods in the constructor but you can't return a `Future` which means you can't use `async`+`await` but you can still use `.then(...)`. That doesn't mean you should though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wanted to use await to be sure my input is valid at the end of my constructor execution. I wiil find another way.

Comment: Again, I didn't say you should use the constructor. If you provide more code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish I might be able to provide better help.

Comment: @matth3o Can you provide more code? This should be easy to figure out then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the [Angular2 Tutorial for Dart](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#!#the-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook) fits your needs almost perfectly.

[Direct link to the code](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-4/blob/master/lib/app_component.dart)